# This If statement not working as expected

Tags: android, ios, flutter, if-statement

My `if` statement isn't working as expected. Any suggestion how to fix it?

```dart
child: RaisedButton(
  color: Colors.green[500],
  if(resources<resToUpabilityOne){
    onPressed:(){
      setStateContext(() {
        resources -= resToUpabilityThree;
        lvl_abilityThree +=1;
        intrest+=lvl_abilityThree;
        resToUpabilityThree=resToUpabilityThree*2;});},
  }else{
    onPressed:(){
    null;
  },
}
```

Comment: The condition is becoming ```true``` in any case? if yes, did you debug it?
Other than that try printing something inside it, the easier way to check whether the condition is turning ```true``` or not

Comment: The condition is true at start, after the click it should be false, and the button should be blocked

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have an if-statement where the constructor expects a named argument.

Try just moving the if-statement down a row.

```
RaisedButton(
  color: Colors.green[500],
  onPressed: () {
  if(resources<resToUpabilityOne) {
    setStateContext(() {
      resources -= resToUpabilityThree;
      lvl_abilityThree +=1;
      intrest+=lvl_abilityThree;
      resToUpabilityThree=resToUpabilityThree*2;});
      },
  },
```

If you want to disable the button in case of that condition, you can try something like this:

```
child: RaisedButton(
  color: Colors.green[500],
  onPressed: (resources < resToUpabilityOne)
      ? () {
          setStateContext(() {
            resources -= resToUpabilityThree;
            lvl_abilityThree += 1;
            intrest += lvl_abilityThree;
            resToUpabilityThree = resToUpabilityThree * 2;
          });
        }
      : null,
),
```

Comment: Which part, and why?

Comment: Not a whole lot to go with there..Try updating your question to be more precise and provide more details, what you expect should happen and what actually happens. Have a glance at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as well. Good luck!

Comment: I'm glad to hear! Accept the answer if it helped you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can't put an if condition in the middle of your `Widget` properties. To do what you want to do, move the condition to an `onPressed` method and then call that method on the `onPressed` call of the widget:

```
RaisedButton(
  color: Colors.green[500],
  onPressed: () => onPressed()

  ...
```

```
void onPressed() {
  if(resources<resToUpabilityOne){
    setStateContext(() {
      resources -= resToUpabilityThree;
      lvl_abilityThree +=1;
      intrest+=lvl_abilityThree;
      resToUpabilityThree=resToUpabilityThree*2;
    });
  },
}
```

Comment: It does not work, beacause i create earlier builder which have StateSetter to refresh showModalBottomSheet with value of seStateContent, so flutter shows undefined variable.

Comment: The simple example I gave you works. It's a standard implementation. The error is somewhere in your code. Somewhere you haven't shown us.